# SIP Client not sending OPTIONS request

Tags: asterisk, sip

I am having an Asterisk server running and my two SIP clients are connected to this server correctly. The server sends OPTIONS request to SIP clients on periodic intervals when option `qualify` is turned yes. I would like to know why the SIP clients is not sending OPTIONS request to server and what need to be done to accomplish this. I am using free SIP clients in Android phone.

Comment: Maybe you should address this to sipclient DOCs? Why you asking it here?

Comment: @arheops didn't get solution that why we ask in stackoverflow :)

Comment: Common. If you even can't inform comunity about software version - no way got answer

Comment: @arheops My bad Asterisk version is 13 and SIP client used is https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mizuvoip.mizudroid.app&hl=en_IN, but question is ageneric one none of the installed SIP clients is sending OPTIONS message so is there any generic setting required to be done in Asterisk or SIP client?

Comment: If the client responses on OPTIONS from "qualify" with a error, then asterisk knows the client is online. It is not neccessary that the client responding wit a "OK".

Answer (score 0):

The soft-phone uses certainly a lightweight keep alive method 'crlfcrlf' , go to the NAT keep-alive *configuration of the softphone* to activate OPTION method.

Comment: which softphone has this feature.